# Mysql left join same table sum wrong results

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have a problem with a query which should do the following:

1. Get specific records and calculate some of their values for specific period of time
2. Calculate same values of these keywords for another period of time

This should happen into 1 query. I was able to write it but SUM() returns wrong value much higher than normal. I think that this is because of LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS table1.id, table1.KeywordId, table1.AccountName, table1.CampaignName, table1.AdGroupName, table1.Keyword, table1.MatchType, SUM(table1.Spend)/SUM(table1.Clicks) AS AverageCpc, SUM(table1.Impressions) AS Impressions, (SUM(table1.Clicks)*table1.revenue_price)/SUM(table1.Impressions) AS Ctr, SUM(table1.Impressions*table1.AveragePosition)/SUM(table1.Impressions) AS AveragePosition, SUM(table1.Clicks) AS Clicks, SUM(table1.Spend) AS Spend, SUM(table1.free_joins) AS FreeJoins, SUM(table1.paid_joins) AS PaidJoins, SUM(table1.paid_joins)*table1.revenue_price AS Revenue, (SUM(table1.paid_joins)*table1.revenue_price)-SUM(table1.Spend) AS Profit, (SUM(table1.paid_joins)*table1.revenue_price)/SUM(table1.Clicks) AS RevPerClick, table1.CurrentMaxCpc, SUM(table2.Impressions) AS Impressions_chg, SUM(table2.Clicks) AS Clicks_chg, SUM(table2.Impressions*table2.AveragePosition)/SUM(table2.Impressions) AS AveragePosition_chg, (SUM(table2.Clicks)*table2.revenue_price)/SUM(table2.Impressions) AS Ctr_chg, SUM(table2.Spend)/SUM(table2.Clicks) AS AverageCpc_chg, table2.CurrentMaxCpc as CurrentMaxCpc_chg, SUM(table2.free_joins) AS FreeJoins_chg, SUM(table2.paid_joins) AS PaidJoins_chg
            FROM keywords_stats_google_naughtymeetings as table1
            LEFT JOIN keywords_stats_google_naughtymeetings as table2
            ON table1.keywordId = table2.keywordId
            WHERE table1.timeperiod >= '2012-05-21 00:00:00' and table1.timeperiod <= '2012-05-27 00:00:00'
            AND table2.timeperiod >= '2012-05-14' and table2.timeperiod <= '2012-05-20'

            GROUP BY table1.KeywordId, table1.MatchType, table1.revenue_price, table2.KeywordId, table2.MatchType, table2.revenue_price
            ORDER BY  FreeJoins
                    asc
            LIMIT 0, 10
```

Can someone give me an advice how I can get correct SUM results?

Comment: Did you try it only with `JOIN`? I don't think you need `LEFT JOIN` here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `INNER JOIN` here. Try to replace the `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.

P.S.
I don't get exactly what you want, but I think this idea should be simpler.

```
(SELECT id, fields_for_first_period_of_time
  FROM keywords_stats_google_naughtymeetings) t1
  JOIN
(SELECT id, fields_for_second_period_of_time
  FROM keywords_stats_google_naughtymeetings) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

This is just a sketch of the idea. I mean get the results with two separate queries. And then join them. This will be easier for debugging. I hope this can help you.

Comment: I tried with JOIN and INNER JOIN and it's not working again. Here is screenshot which I will try to explain:http://screencast.com/t/XpsiYlq6f

Comment: Maybe try to split your query for the two timeperiods, like I suggested. You could easily spot the error then.

Comment: I tried this way but the syntax you proposed didn't work out. I'm still looking for a similar example.